# BIRT suppress multiple duplicate columns

Tags: reporting, birt, birt-emitter

I am working on a BIRT report. Its records are grouped on the basis of the status column. I was looking for an option in the Eclipse BIRT tool by which I can hide combinations of multiple columns in a row which are repeating. I have attached screenshots for both the current report and the expected report structure.

I tried the "suppress duplicate" option but that is limited to a single column. I am not able to apply this on multiple columns together. I couldn't figure out any other option. Please suggest any solution in the tool or do I need to change my query to return the result in the expected format?

**Actual Result:**

[image]

**Expected Result:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are three obvious ways to hide duplicate values.
All of these require you to configure this per column (BTW I don't understand why you consider this to be a problem).

1. As you already did: Use "suppress duplicates" at the column level.
2. Add more groups to your table *after* the existing group.
   E.g. one group for the first column (whatever that is).
   Then you can choose "Drop" "detail" in the properties of the corresponding group header cell. It's a bit difficult to get the layout right this way.
3. In your data set, if it's SQL, you can use a little construnct with CASE and the LAG analytic function to compare the column value to that of the previous row, and if they are equal, return NULL instead (pure SQL solution).

Comment: Are you familiar with any JavaScript way to achieve it? I was thinking if somehow If I can iterate through all the rows on some events and compare current row with next row and set values to null as per need... hvb

Comment: Though that's possible, it would be much more complicated than Suppress Duplicates.